# Flex 3 Set Maximum and minimum X Axis value in bar chart

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, bar-chart

I want to set Maximum and minimum value for X axis in bar chart in flex action script 3 file.

Following line in working in MXML file but I want these code in actionscript 3.

```
<mx:BarChart x="46" y="115" id="myChart">
    <mx:horizontalAxis>     
        <mx:LinearAxis minimum="-20000" maximum="20000">                
        </mx:LinearAxis>
    </mx:horizontalAxis>
</mx:BarChart>
```

can anybody change this into Actionscript 3.

thanks..

Comment: Make sure you indent 5 spaces before you post code - something tells me not all of what you intended is showing up.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
var vAxis:LinearAxis = new LinearAxis();
vAxis.maximum = 100;
vAxis.minimum = 0;
```

This won't guarantee a label but it will keep the axis at a fixed size.

Answer (score 0):

In MXML

```
<mx:ColumnChart ...>
    <mx:verticalAxis>
        <mx:LinearAxis id="vAxis"
                 minimum="0" 
                 maximum="100" />
    </mx:verticalAxis>
</mx:ColumnChart>
```

For actionscript see slashnick's answer.